# NLua - How to implement Roblox like function security?

Tags: lua, security, roblox

Roblox uses [Normal Identities](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Normal_Identities), basicly they assign a lua block/object to a certain number. They use 2 for Scripts and LocalScripts, which can only use non-secured functions, while the command bar can access everything that is LocalUserSecurity and RobloxPlaceSecurity. How can I implement this type of Lua Security into NLua?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to create a safe environment to Lua, is creating a sandbox using lua. You just need to "hide" the unsafe functions the let only the "safe" functions visible.

For exemple:

os.exit = function () {} -- after this os.exit() will be harmless.

There is more info here http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes